# Play one part of GIF first, then loop a certain section indefinitely

Tags: jquery, animation, svg, gif, animated-gif

I have an animated gif with transparency over at my website [here](http://lakewoodcreativeco.com/).

Ideally I would like this to play the animation once and then repeat a few frames that has the entire logo in it, but it doesn't look like a single gif will be able to accomplish this.

Doing some research it looks like I have a few options, but I'm not sure what's best in a scenario like this.

1. Use javascript to time the gif and then swap images out when it *should* be done playing. This seems very unreliable and on slow connections it probably won't function like I want to at all. I don't think there's other ways to detect when a gif animation has finished playing, but I might be wrong on that.
2. Use a format other than gif that might be able to accomplish this for me.
3. Edit the gif so that it only plays through once, and make the last frame a still of what I'd like. This would remove any animation and I'd rather go for that hand drawn, animated feel but I have a feeling I might end up doing this.
4. Somehow find a pure javascript/svg + path solution which seems incredibly difficult & not something that I can do relatively quickly at all.

Has anyone faced a problem similar to this that has any suggestions?

Comment: Here's what I would do: Combine all the frames into a single filmstrip image (transparent PNG would be best, with antialiasing if possible). Set this as the background of a div element with the height of a single frame, and then use Javascript (or JQuery) to animate over the required frames by setting the `background-position` CSS property to suitable values. You can trigger this animation from the image's `onload` event, so timing shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: is there any guides or tools you know to help with this kind of thing? for the javascript part especially. i would probably try & use an array.. wouldn't triggering with `onload` cause the frames to be out of order if one image downloads before the next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine all the frames into a single filmstrip image (transparent PNG would be best, with antialiasing if possible). Set this as the background of a div element with the height of a single frame, and then animate over the required frames by setting the background-position CSS property to suitable values.

Here's a simple example made with a [filmstrip image containing 14 frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppyyt.png), where the last 3 frames are played in a loop:

```js
$(function() {
  var ani = {
    frame_height: 200,
    num_frames: 14,
    loop_frame: 11,
    frame_duration: 125,
    cur_frame: 0
  };
  window.setInterval(
    function() {
      $('#draw').css( 'background-position-y',
                      (-ani.frame_height * ani.cur_frame ) + 'px'
                    );
      ani.cur_frame = (ani.cur_frame + 1) % ani.num_frames;
      if (ani.cur_frame == 0) ani.cur_frame = ani.loop_frame;
    },
    ani.frame_duration
  );
});
```

```css
#draw {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppyyt.png) top center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="draw"></div>
```

Note: If you set the default background of the animated div to the first frame of the animation, you don't need to set an `onload` event handler because JQuery will only run your code once it has loaded.

To convert your animated GIF into a filmstrip, I recommend using [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/). There are just two simple steps:

1. Unpack the animated GIF into a numbered series of individual frames:

   ```
   convert -coalesce Logo-norepeat-transparent-white-big.gif f_%05d.png
   ```
2. Stitch these frames together, one above the other:

   ```
   convert -append f_[0-9]*.png logo_frames.png
   ```

If the frames in your GIF animation have different durations, then things will be a little more complicated, but the basic principle is the same.

Comment: This works great! Do you know any good ways to make this responsive?

Comment: Try adding `background-size:100%` to the div's style. You'll probably have to change the `background-position-y` values to percentages in this case.