# Can PNGs (or GIFs) loop only the last few images (rather than all the images)

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I want to have a PNG sequence that displays 68 frames of animation and then loops the final 20 frames x number of times.

I based my code on the suggestion from 'r3mainer' on your page:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43595504/play-one-part-of-gif-first-then-loop-a-certain-section-indefinitely]

But I can not get it to work.

I created the vertical PNG 'film strip', a CSS file with the appropriate background style info, and a JS file referenced in an HTML.

With the PNG, the JS, the HTML, and the CSS uploaded all I get for an image on the page is the first 'frame' of the PNG strip. There are no error messages.

I think there's something I don't understand about how the JS code should be deployed.

Here's my HTML file:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Strip Test</title>    
    <script src="film_strip_script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="draw.css">
 </head>

<body>
<div id="draw"></div>
</body>
```

The CSS:

```
#draw {
  width: 279px;
  height: 202px;
  margin:  0 auto;
  background: url(basquiat_strip.png) top center;
}
```

JavaScript file:

```
$(function() {
  var ani = {
    frame_height: 202,
    num_frames: 68,
    loop_frame: 30,
    frame_duration: 1,
    cur_frame: 0
  };
  window.setInterval(
    function() {
      $('#draw').css( 'background-position-y',
                      (-ani.frame_height * ani.cur_frame ) + 'px'
                    );
      ani.cur_frame = (ani.cur_frame + 1) % ani.num_frames;
      if (ani.cur_frame == 0) ani.cur_frame = ani.loop_frame;
    },
    ani.frame_duration
  );
});
```

Comment: No. For GIF, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF#Animated_GIF perfectly explains why (look for `delay`), and for APNG, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG#File_format explains why equally well (look for `fcTL`).